# display dropdownlist value same after came back to same page

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a page with a `select` list a follows

```
<select class="othdebt" id="othdebt" name="othdebt">
    <option value="Cate" >Categorical</option>
    <option value="Cont">Continuous</option>
    <option value="Data">Date</option>
</select>
```

When I go to some other page and came back to the `select` list page then I want to see the same selected option.

I use the following jQuery to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".othdebt").each(function(){
        var $titleId = $(this).attr('id');
        var $cookieValue = $.cookies.get($titleId);
        if ($cookieValue) {
            $(this).val($cookieValue);
        }                       
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working any other suggestion to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `.attr('id').val`? `val` is a method not a property and you cannot use it after calling `attr` as getter.

Comment: attr( attributeName )
attributeNameThe name of the attribute to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally i found the solution for myself

here is the 
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PnJ9Y/)

```
/* Here's the actual code. */

if($.cookie('remember_select') != null) {

    $('.select_class option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

}

$('.select_class').change(function() {

    $.cookie('remember_select', $('.select_class option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});

});​
```

Comment: but the code which you gave is not working.. you better try your code in jsfiddle and see.. any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `id` incorrectly. Try this:

```
var titleId = $(this).attr('id');
```

Or alternatively:

```
var titleId = this.id;
```

Notice I haev also removed the `$` from the start of the variable name. This convention is reserved for variables which contain jQuery objects - this does not.

Comment: i have tried var titleId = $(this).attr('id'); but still not working

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NPuF6/. My guess would be the problem is elsewhere in your code and this is just a symptom. Check the console for errors.

Comment: please recheck select any other option in the drop down give refresh and see still the first item occurs

Comment: Well that's because you're not setting the cookie anywhere, only getting it.

Comment: please how to do that any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Keep all of the code in document.ready()

**Edit:** To set a cookies

```
$(".othdebt").​change(function(){
    $.cookies('titleId',$(this).val());
});​
```

To get a cookie while loading a page

```
document.ready(function(){
$(".othdebt").each(function() {
    //var titleId = $(this).attr('id');
    var $cookieValue = $.cookies.get('titleId');
    if ($cookieValue) {
        $(this).val($cookieValue);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: r u sure..u r setting cookie correctly??...here we are just getting the cookie...

Answer (score 0):

First, set cookie with this native javascript function.

```
document.cookie = 'othdebt=Data';
```

then get cookie with this

```
var objId = $('.othdebt').attr('id');
var cookieValue = document.cookie.match( '(^|;) ?' + objId + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );
 if ( cookieValue )
    cv = ( unescape ( cookieValue[2] ) );
else
    cv = null;
```

cv holds the cookie value

```
 $(".othdebt option").each(function(){
  if (cv == $(this).val())
  {
    $('.othdebt').val(cv);
  }
});
```

I have tested this already and it work for me ;)

Comment: jquery.cookie.js and  jquery.min.js